# Why are the blueprints of old satellites still not available to public?

Tags: artificial-satellite, launch-vehicle

There are old, now mostly useless blueprints of old satellites, (or rockets, or pieces of software, or engineer's notes, e.t.c) but they are still closed to public. Why? Can it harm the Space Agency which manufactured them somehow?

Comment: Which space agency are you talking about?

Comment: Just as an example, none of them share such a data (mostly)

Comment: Are they unwilling or just unbothering to?

Comment: If I suspect correctly, your native language is using "ship" also for satellites (aka "spaceship"). Beware, it is a possible source of misunderstanding, on English, "ship" means only the large steel boxes swimming on the oceans of the Earth.

Comment: The program of the moon lander is available on the Github. It is in assembly for an ancient cpu. :-)

Comment: I'd argue that very few blueprints of old space technology are really useless today. Let me spin your own question for you: it the blueprints _were_ useless, why does it bother you they are not published?

Comment: @NathanTuggy The one that manufactured them! (Although space agencies don't manufacture satellites AFAIK)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Rockets (even old designs) are capable of delivering a nuclear weapon anywhere on Earth. Governments don't want this technology to fall into the wrong hands.
2. Publishing a design takes a lot of effort. The complete design for a rocket easily exceeds a million drawings and hundreds of thousands of pages of supporting documents. For an old rocket, all of that only exists on paper or microfilm, so it'd cost millions to scan it all and make the documents accessible.

To address the comments:

Lots of information is available to the public. You can buy entire books on various space projects (I've seen books on the Shuttle, the Apollo project, the Curiosity rover for example).

You won't find much if you search for "satellite blueprint" in your search engine. The word 'blueprint' has a very specific meaning: this is a copy of an engineering drawing using a contact print process on light-sensitive sheets, i.e. a copy of one drawing showing one individual part.

What you're looking for is a diagram or a cross-section. The Flight Global archive is a good source for those, e.g. I found a diagram of the [Apollo-Soyuz Test project from 1975](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1975/1975%20-%201147.html). 
Or enter the words 'Soyuz diagram' into your search engine and do an image search.

Comment: In some cases, the detailed design work belongs to the corporations that did the engineering work, not to a government space agency accountable to the citizens of a given country. Those corporations don't have any financial incentive to make those documents available, and substantial incentive to keep them secret from their competitors.

Comment: The terms to look up for point 1 is the [Missile Technology Control Regime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile_Technology_Control_Regime).

Comment: Hello Hobbes, I agree that detailed designs giving dimensions, matl of construction etc. should not be shared, but conceptual cross section explaining the working in details can always be made available. Do you know any such site which provides them. In fact animated operations are the best guide.

Comment: @Niranjan Why would they release those? What would be the benefit?

Comment: I would add reason 3 to the answer: unless the reader had hundreds or thousands of hours to spend, and the right level of specialist professional knowledge, they wouldn't be able to find much "interesting information" in the documents anyway.

Comment: There's _also_ the fact that some of the documentation, especially for historical hardware, may have been lost or deliberately destroyed. The Saturn V is a classic example - NASA's been forced to redevelop a lot of the tech required for high-mass launchers from scratch, simply because of the fact that a lot of the documentation and drawings for the S5 were thrown away or burned.

Comment: That's an urban legend. The drawings still exist. Some of the supporting documentation no longer exists (many of the thousands of component suppliers have gone out of business, for example).

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz source?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Apparently I'm wrong. Fair enough.

Comment: @user71659 - Right, they're all just **ballistic missiles** until you decide to make them complete an orbit. 'Why are the blueprints of old *ballistic missiles* still not available to the public?' Well, duh. Kinda sad though that because of the treaty some countries have "shelved or eliminated missile or space launch vehicle programs".